# Transitive action of a $p$-group on minimal block systems

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I have trouble proving the following theorem:

Let $P$ be a transitive $p$-subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(A)$ with $|A| > 1$. Then any minimal $P$-block system consists of exactly $p$ blocks. Furthermore, the subgroup $P'$ which stabilizes all of the blocks has index $p$ in $P$.

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that you mean maximal $P$-block system (i.e. blocks not contained in any larger blocks) rather than minimal $P$-block system. As a hint, note that all maximal subgroups of $P$ have index $p$ in $P$, and so any primitive action of $P$ must have degree $p$.

Comment: I actually mean minimal.  A $G$-block system is minimal, if $G$ acts primitively on the blocks.

Comment: That's what I call a maximal block system (because the blocks are maximal).

Comment: So, in the paper the proof just goes like this: "The quotient $P/P'$ is a primitive $p$-group (acting on the blocks) and so the order of $P/P' =$ the number of blocks $= p$." I realized that I still don't understand this.

Comment: I know that $P/P'$ is transitive on the blocks. Therefore, the action $P/P'$ on the blocks is transitive and has only one orbit of size $p^k$. But how do we prove that $P/P'$ is primitive?

Comment: Oh, I see... since the action of $P$ on the blocks is primitive (that is the assumption), we know that also the action of $P/P'$ on the blocks is primitive.

Comment: So, what I do not understand why $|P/P'| =$ the number of blocs $= p$. According to your hint $P'$ is a maximal subgroup of $P$.  Why is this so?

Comment: There is a general result that if $G$ acts transitively on a set $X$, then the action is primitive if and only if the stabilizer in $G$ of a point in $X$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I see. Do you have some reference to this result (book, website)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about Lemma on Primitive Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912055/question-about-lemma-on-primitive-groups)